# How to disable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries on SQL Server 2000

Tags: security, sql-server

We juste had a security audit that found that, if you get access to our database (SQLInjection for example), you can easily send all the content of the database to a remote SQL Server.

The recommendation is to disable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries. I found a lot of articles on how to do that on SQL Server 2005, but not on SQL Server 2000.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Distributed Query Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175255(SQL.80).aspx) page: "For each instance of SQL Server 2000, members of the sysadmin fixed server role can enable or disable the use of ad-hoc connector names for an OLE DB provider using the SQL Server DisallowAdhocAccess property."

Comment: He he, you were faster! +1

Comment: Hey, thanks for the super-fast and correct answer !